# (SQL) WHERE clause not working in its most simple way?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

SQL beginner here. I have this database: https://github.com/socratica/data/blob/master/earthquake.csv

I'm running a simple Query such as:

```sql
SELECT place, DEPTH1 , OCCURED_ON from EARTHQUAKE1;
```

I execute it, and get the info I need. However, when I add `WHERE depth1 = 35;` (I edited the depth col just in case it was conflicting with some other clause)

the GUI returns an error. I tried adding `'` and using like, also using `TRIM` but no luck. I also tried retrieving data from another col, but still no good.  What is it that I'm doing brutally wrong?

*Thanks in advance!*

[image: Here's a screenshot of the database info just in case it makes it easier to understand.]

Comment: What exactly is the error you get?

Comment: do you need that semi colon there on the first line?

Comment: Did you put a `;` after `EARTHQUAKE1` and then add the `where` clause, as it shows on your screenshot ?

Comment: @mkrieger1: Error occurred during SQL query execution

_Reason:
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE depth1 = 35' at line 1_

Comment: OH MAN, I knew I was being brutally stupid. Thanks! How do I mark it as answered?

Comment: To save blushes, delete is the preferred option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a semicolon after your FROM and before your WHERE.
SQL is reading the WHERE as a separate statement and failing.

The ; is a statement terminator.

Comment: Thank you so much, and sorry for being so distracted! I'm seriously on my own on this and need it for work, so I really appreciate the help!